# How to display the result into a TextView

Tags: java, android, textview

New to android development and I'm confused about displaying the data onto the layout.

I'm trying to print out the url address onto a EditView called `sharedText`

Goal is to send the url to my EditView by clicking on the share button from the browser settings and get this in my LogCat when the shared button is clicked but no url address displayed on the app.

> **'2020-04-30 12:04:59.730 3675-3675/com.e.testshare D/MainActivity: sharedText : [https://www.bbc.co.uk/news'](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news%27)**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent != null) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        String type = intent.getType();

        if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
            if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
                handleReceivedText(intent); // Handle text being sent
            }
        }

void handleReceivedText(Intent intent) {
    String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
    if (sharedText != null) {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "sharedText : " + sharedText);
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

        i.putExtra("SHAREDTEXT", sharedText);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.e.testshare">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:label="Share Testing">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

layout:

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/sharedText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="UrlAddress"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="78dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="89dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

if `sharedText` is your `EditText` try to do `sharedText.setText(sharedText)`.
Also it is bad practice to use same variable namings for different things. Better would be `sharedTextEditText` and `sharedText`

```
 void handleReceivedText(Intent intent) {
            String text= intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
            if (text!= null) {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "sharedText : " + sharedText);
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                EditText sharedText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sharedText);
                sharedText.setText(text)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. Made the changes and this is the response error: cannot find symbol
        if (sharedText != null) {  Its says i should create local variable sharedText. If i do this i get the error sharedText is already defined in method

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much

the code above you posted didn't work but changed sharedText to text on the log.d line

```
void handleReceivedText(Intent intent) {
            String text= intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
            if (text!= null) {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "sharedText : " + text);
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                EditText sharedText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sharedText);
                sharedText.setText(text)
            }
        }
```